# How to get my Bedrock skin off of my mobile and onto my laptop?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to get my Minecraft Bedrock/Pocket Edition skin onto Windows 10.
I've already tried searching it up on Youtube, Google and Reddit and nothing came up.

Comment: How did you initially install the skin? Because you could go to the website you got the skin from and download it on your computer.

Comment: i made the skin on the in game skin maker

Answer (score 2):

If the skin was created through the in-game [Character Creator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Character_Creator#:%7E:text=The%20Character%20Creator%20is%20a,button%20on%20the%20main%20menu.), or purchased through the Marketplace then you would simply need to sign in with the same Xbox Live account on the mobile device, on Minecraft for Windows 10. Any Character Creator or Marketplace skins that were saved in a skin slot on mobile should now sync to Windows 10, or any other version of Minecraft that you sign in to with the same account. If you still don't see your skin(s) in the Dressing Room tab, they can still be recreated through the Character Creator or downloaded again from the Marketplace, as long as the purchases were made on the same account.

Any skins uploaded to Minecraft from the "Import" option do not sync between devices, so you will need to find the original image file for that skin, and then transfer it to your Windows device where you should be able to import it again. Custom skins can only be imported on mobile and Windows 10.

For more information, see the support article [Minecraft Skins for Bedrock Versions](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408902716557-Minecraft-Skins-for-Bedrock-Versions-).